# Can jQuery replaceWith() do this?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to use jQuery replaceWith to change a truckload of div's that have id's that start with TMBOBJ

```
<div id="TMBOBJ7DC931A601118D2" style=" position:absolute; top:40px; left:446px; width:150px; height:100px;  z-index:2;">
<a href="Untitled_1/imag000A.html" onclick="newWin('Untitled_1/imag000A.html',333,500);return false;" target="_blank">
<img src="Untitled_1/imag000.jpg" width=150 height=100 border=0>
</a>
</div>


<div id="TMBOBJ7DC931A60C7D2" style=" position:absolute; top:26px; left:52px; width:150px; height:100px;  z-index:3;">
<a href="Untitled_1/imag001A.html" onclick="newWin('Untitled_1/imag001A.html',333,500);return false;" target="_blank">
<img src="Untitled_1/imag001.jpg" width=150 height=100 border=0>
</a>
</div>
```

...Into these?

```
<div id="TMBOBJ7DC931A601118D2" style=" position:absolute; top:40px; left:446px;    width:150px; height:100px;  z-index:2;">
<a class="new" href="Untitled_1/imag000A.jpg">
<img src="Untitled_1/imag000.jpg" width=150 height=100 border=0>
</a>
</div>

<div id="TMBOBJ7DC931A60C7D2" style=" position:absolute; top:26px; left:52px; width:150px; height:100px;  z-index:3;">
<a class="new" href="Untitled_1/imag001A.jpg">
<img src="Untitled_1/imag001.jpg" width=150 height=100 border=0>
</a>
</div>
```

I couldn't even get past just changing .html into .jpg on just one. Thanks.

Comment: Is the only thing you are trying to do is change the .html extension to .jpg and remove the onclick?

Comment: I'm trying to both Mark so they look like the lower div's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tr[y](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/d3BAB/http://) this selector to get div's that start with

```
$('[id^=TMBOBJ]')  // Get all elements with id 's that start with TMBOBJ

$('[id^=TMBOBJ]').each(function() {

     var $a = $(this).find('a');
     $a.attr('href' , $a.attr('href').replace('html', 'jpg'));
     $a.removeAttr('onclick');
     $a.removeAttr('target');

});
```

Check FIDDLE

Comment: Excellent I should be able get that to work, just need to run it through.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi try using this code:

```
$('div[id^=TMBOBJ]').each( function (index, element) {
    var href = $(element).children('a').attr('href');
    $(element).children('a').attr('href', href.replace('.html', '.jpg')).addClass('new');
});
```